# How to kill previous service before start new service in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-service, ondestroy, android-ondestroy

I am coding an Android app using Android Studio.

My service class takes the values from the main activity class when starting the service.

However, when I reassign the values in the main activity, the change is not applied to the value in the service. Then, I tried to start a new service every time after reassigning the values, but it makes two services run at the same time.

Therefore, I would like to know if is there any way to remove the previous service when I start the new one. I am not sure if onDestroy() can do what I want. As far as I tried, I still can not make it.

This is the service class code:

public class ForegroundService extends Service {

```
double x1 = MainActivity.x1;
double y1 = MainActivity.y1;
double radius_ = MainActivity.radius_;
int k = MainActivity.k;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        Log.e("Service", "Running " + String.valueOf(x1));
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    ).start();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

After reassign x1, it shows two x1 value every one second:

E/Service: Running 35.6761919

E/Service: Running 35.4436739

Comment: "but it makes two services run at the same time" -- no, it does not. Services are natural singletons; there will be either zero or one instance of a given service running at any given time. Bear in mind that very few apps nowadays need a service at all; you might wish to reconsider having one in the first place.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've just edited the question, hope you don't mind helping me understand the problem. I don't understand if the first service was gone, why it keeps printing two values of x1 every one second.

Comment: You create a `Thread` on `onStartCommand()`. You do nothing to clean up that `Thread` in `onDestroy()`. So, that `Thread` continues to exist and do its work after the service is destroyed.

Comment: Could you please suggest me the way to clean up the previous Thread after I stopService() and startSevice()?

Comment: I recommend getting rid of the `Service` entirely. It is highly unlikely that you need one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Service` is never shut down. When you start it the first time from the `Activity` by calling `startService()`, the `Service` instance is created and this will initialize the values of `x, y, k, etc.` from `MainActivity` and `onStartCommand()` is called. You then start a thread that counts and logs. This thread runs forever (until Android kills off the OS process hosting your app). If you now do something in your `Activity` that changes the values of `xc, y, k, etc.` and then calls `startService()` again, this doesn't start another `Service` instance. Your `Service` is already running. So it just calls `onStartCommand()` again. This starts another thread that counts and logs. Now you have 2 threads that are counting and logging.

Also, it is bad practice to have a `Service` copy values from an `Activity` like this. It is better to put these values in the `Intent` you pass to `startService()` as "extras". You can then access these values in `onStartCommand()` as the `Intent` is passed through as a parameter to `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: I tried using putExtra() in MainActivity, but it says getExtra() is deprecated. How to fix this?

Comment: `putExtra()` and `getExtra()` are definitely not deprecated. Please edit your question and show what you did and what the problem is. You can definitely put data in an `Intent` using "extras"

Comment: Sorry, I mean I tried to add this in Foreground.class

`Intent receiveIntent = getIntent();`
`x1 = receiveIntent.getDoubleExtra("x1", x1);`

but getIntent(); is deprecated.

Comment: The `Intent` is passed as a parameter to `onStartCommand()`. Where are you trying to call `getIntent()`??

Comment: In ForegroundService.class

Comment: There is no `getIntent()` method in `Service`. Anyway, the `Intent` with the "extras" you have access to in `onStartCommand()` as a parameter. Get your "extras" from there.

Comment: Okay, now I can receive values from MainActivity writing this is Service.
`String X1 = intent.getStringExtra("x1");`
`String Y1 = intent.getStringExtra("y1");`
`x1 = Double.parseDouble(X1);`
`y1 = Double.parseDouble(Y1);`
But I think the values will be sent only when startService right? Is there any way the link the values between MainActivity and Service all the time without startService again?

Comment: The simple way is to put them in `static` variables. These can be accessed from anywhere. This, however, is a hack and isn't recommended. I don't know your requirements. Normally you would use something like `LiveData` for this, you can read about it here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: You can also use bound services and AIDL and have your `Activity` bind to the `Service` and then call methods in the `Service` to update the values, but you would need to explain i more detail what you are trying to accomplish.